# onLoadFinished is not always being called when loader restarted

Tags: android, android-loadermanager, asynctaskloader

After I let my user download files to cloud, I want my app to restart its loader.

Previously, `onLoadFinished` is not always being called (randomly), when I wrote my code in the following way

```
public void reloadAfterOpenFromCloud() {
    LoaderManager loaderManager = this.getLoaderManager();
    loaderManager.restartLoader(0, bundle, this);
}
```

After referring to the discussion in [Android - onLoadFinished not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014992/android-onloadfinished-not-called), I modify my code to

```
public void reloadAfterOpenFromCloud() {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014992/android-onloadfinished-not-called
    // This seems to be a realiable way, to make sure onCreateLoader and onLoadFinished will
    // be called.
    LoaderManager loaderManager = this.getLoaderManager();
    Loader loader = loaderManager.getLoader(0);
    if (loader != null) {
        loaderManager.destroyLoader(0);
    }
    loaderManager.restartLoader(0, bundle, this);
}
```

This reduces the chance of not calling `onLoadFinished`. However still, it will randomly happen, if I

1. Do a clear cache, clean uninstall on my app.
2. Install the app.
3. Run `reloadAfterOpenFromCloud`. Again, randomly, `onLoadFinished` will not be called.

When `onLoadFinished` is not being called, if I run `reloadAfterOpenFromCloud` again, `onLoadFinished` will be called.

I'm using latest `com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0` and `targetSdkVersion 25`.

I was wondering, is there any realiable workaround, to ensure `onLoadFinished` is always being called, when loader restarted?

---

The following are part of my code snippets.

```
public void reloadAfterOpenFromCloud() {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014992/android-onloadfinished-not-called
    // This seems to be a realiable way, to make sure onCreateLoader and onLoadFinished will
    // be called.
    LoaderManager loaderManager = this.getLoaderManager();
    Loader loader = loaderManager.getLoader(0);
    if (loader != null) {
        loaderManager.destroyLoader(0);
    }
    loaderManager.restartLoader(0, bundle, this);
}

static class HomeMenuRowInfosLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<HomeMenuRowInfo>> {

    private List<HomeMenuRowInfo> homeMenuRowInfos = null;

    public HomeMenuRowInfosLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public List<HomeMenuRowInfo> loadInBackground() {
        ...
        return homeMenuRowInfos;
    }

    /**
     * Handles a request to cancel a load.
     */
    @Override 
    public void onCanceled(List<HomeMenuRowInfo> homeMenuRowInfos) {
        super.onCanceled(homeMenuRowInfos);
    }

    /**
     * Handles a request to stop the Loader.
     * Automatically called by LoaderManager via stopLoading.
     */
    @Override 
    protected void onStopLoading() {
        // Attempt to cancel the current load task if possible.
        cancelLoad();
    }

    /**
     * Handles a request to start the Loader.
     * Automatically called by LoaderManager via startLoading.
     */
    @Override        
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        if (this.homeMenuRowInfos != null) {
            deliverResult(this.homeMenuRowInfos);
        }

        if (takeContentChanged() || this.homeMenuRowInfos == null) {
            forceLoad();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles a request to completely reset the Loader.
     * Automatically called by LoaderManager via reset.
     */
    @Override 
    protected void onReset() {
        super.onReset();

        // Ensure the loader is stopped
        onStopLoading();

        // At this point we can release the resources associated with 'apps'
        // if needed.
        this.homeMenuRowInfos = null;
    }        
}

@Override
public Loader<List<HomeMenuRowInfo>> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle bundle) {
    return new HomeMenuRowInfosLoader(this.getActivity());
}

// Not being called always when restart loader
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<HomeMenuRowInfo>> arg0, List<HomeMenuRowInfo> homeMenuRowInfos) {
    ...
```

Comment: Please add the full code for your `HomeMenuRowInfosLoader` class.  I am specifically interested in when `onContentChanged()` is called.

Comment: @krislarson I updated the code. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166363/loadercallbacks-onloadfinished-not-called-if-orientation-change-happens-during-a/47297350#47297350

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement some sort of observer in your `HomeMenuRowInfosLoader` that will call `onContentChanged()` when the user has finished the cloud file transfer.

If `onContentChanged()` is never called, `takeContentChanged()` will always return `false` and `forceLoad()` will not be called within `onStartLoading()` after the first load at which point `homeMenuRowInfos` is not equal to null.

Comment: I had debug. `forceLoad` is called, when the "onLoadFinished is not called" problem occurs.

Comment: If you have a matching `forceLoad` for every `restartLoader` but aren't getting `onLoadFinished`, I'm not sure what that is.  In `loadInBackground`, do you always do `homeMenuRowInfos = new ArrayList<>()` or do you reuse the list?  I see some code in `LoaderManager` that looks like it will skip `onLoadFinished` if the new data == previous data.